# Performace Issue on MATLAB's vector addressing

Tags: matlab

I'm wondering, what is faster for addressing a single Element of a vector:

1) direct access via

```
result = a(index)
```

or

2) access an element via a matrix multiplication e.g

```
a = [1 2 3 4]';
b = [0 0 1 0];
result = b*a;   % Would return 3
```

In my oppinion (which comes from "classic" programming like C++) the first method must be more performant, because of the direct access...the second method would need a iteration through both vectors(?).

The reason why I'm asking is, that matlab is very performant on matrix and vector operations, maybe I am missing any aspect and the second method is more effective...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick test:

```
function [] = fun1()
a = [1 2 3 4]';
b = [0 0 1 0];
tic;
for i=1:1000000
    r = a(3);
end
toc;
end
```

Elapsed time: **0.006 seconds**

Change `a(3)` to `b*a`

Elapsed time: **0.9 seconds**

---

The performance difference is quite obvious(, and you should have done that yourself before asking this question).

Reason behind that:

No matter how efficient MATLAB's calculation is, MATLAB still needs to fetch the number 1 by 1, and do multiplication 1 by 1, and sum up. There is no hope to be faster than a single access.

In your special case, there are all 0's except 1, but it is useless to do optimization for single special case in my opinion, and the best optimization I can come up with still needs to access all the elements for at least once each.

---

EDIT:

<sub>It seems I am in quite good mood today....</sub>

Change `a(3)` to `a(1)*b(1)+a(2)*b(2)+a(3)*b(3)+a(4)*b(4)`

Elapsed time: **0.02 seconds**

It seems that boundary checking (and/or other errands) take more time than the access and calculation.

Comment: Hi Dante Jiang, thanks for your very detailed answer, it confirms my suggestion. And your're absolutely right, I should have done those benchmarl before, but I din't even know that matlab has any method for this. Tanks a lot again!

Comment: @poeschlom: If you're new to performance testing in Matlab, have a look at the "profile" function, too.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you think that multiplying a lot of numbers by zeros would be at all efficient? Even if MATLAB could be smart enough to do a test first before the multiply, it must then still do many tests.

I'm asking this question to make a point, that the dot product cannot possibly be at all efficient. Even if MATLAB were smart enough to know that there was only one element that was non-zero, to know that, it would need to do a search for the non-zero element. And how would MATLAB be smart enough to know that what you have written as a vector*vector dot product is actually intended just to access a single element, instead of a true dot product for nefarious purposes unknown to it?

Answer (score 0):

How about

3) access an element by a boolean index matrix:

```
a = [1 2 3 4]';
b = [0 0 1 0];
result = a(b)
```

It's almost certainly going to be faster than (2), slower than (1).

Comment: This b is not a boolean; it's a double and will error out because it's doing linear indexing and trying to access element 0. You want "b = logical([0 0 1 0]);". Please test code snippets before handing them to the newbies. :)